# Hide a component on click of mat-button and display other one Angular 9

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, typescript2.0

I need to have an intro page in my angular 9 app. There I have a `mat-button` which when I click it I need to display the home page where the main navigation and other stuff is going to be displayed.

What I have try so far is

in my app.component.html

```
<app-main-nav *ngIf="!showActions">
</app-main-nav>
<app-bgphotos ></app-bgphotos>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

in my **app.component.ts**

```
public showActions: boolean;
constructor() { }
ngOnInit() { this.showActions = false; }
public toggle(): void { this.showActions = !this.showActions; }
```

in my homepage.component.html

```
<div class="bgpageland">
<div class="wlctext">
<p>Welcome</p>
<p>serv</p>

<button type="button" (click)="toggle()">Intro</button>
```

Nothing happens both of components are being displayed

see below image

[image]

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you said you have a mat-button which when you click it should displays the home page

you can use angular router

first import  `Router`

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

then your logic should be

```
public showActions: boolean;
constructor( private router: Router ) { }
ngOnInit() { this.showActions = false; }
public toggle(): void { 
  this.showActions = !this.showActions; 
  this.router.navigate(['/home']);
}
```

Comment: I just tried your code it doesn't "hide" the `<app-bgphotos ></app-bgphotos>` component. Any idea?

Comment: I correct some things in my code. It works! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Actually you bind the click event in "homepage.component.html" and the click event is defined in "app.component.ts". If you want to call a function in parent component from the clild component you should use EventEmitter and use @Output binding to "homepage.component.html".